# Nested directives won't work as desired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS, was trying to use nested directives. I have a home layout which has following

`<product-list></product-list>`

This directive has a template which is present in another file. It has content like that

`<div class="products">
<product prod-id="{{product.id}}" ng-repeat="product in products"></product>
</div>`

The problem I am facing is when the `product-list` directive is compiled it isn't able to understand `product.id` in the expression. It gives me some error like that

`Error: Syntax Error: Token 'product.id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{product.id}}] starting at [product.id}}].`

The directives are defined as

```
app.directive('productList', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'ProductListCtrl',
    templateUrl: base_url + 'partials/directives/product-list.html'
};
});

app.directive('product', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
    templateUrl: base_url + 'partials/directives/product.html',
    scope: {
        prodId: '=prodId'
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        var num = $scope.$eval(attrs.prodId);
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(num))){
            $scope.prodId = num;
        }
    }
};
});
```

**UPDATE: Added controller for directive**

```
myApp.controller("ProductListCtrl", ['$scope', 'ProductModel', '$stateParams', '$location', function($scope, ProductModel, $stateParams, $location) {
$scope.products = {};

//Fetch the products if we have some category for a given state
if(typeof $stateParams.categoryId != 'undefined' && typeof $stateParams.prodId == 'undefined'){        
    //Fetch products for selected category and page
    ProductModel.getProductsByCategory($stateParams.categoryId, function(products){
        $scope.products = products;
    });
} 

}]);
```

Please guide what I am doing wrong or missing anything.

Comment: please post your controller. And will be bater to show your code in Plunker or Fiddle

Comment: Thansk @MaximShoustin for quick response... In plunker I will have write many things... like the `products` are coming from a webservice. But let me share the `controller` if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing happened not sure if its the right way, but it worked for me :)

I used

`<product prod-id="product.id" ng-repeat="product in products"></product>`

instead of

`<product prod-id="{{product.id}}" ng-repeat="product in products"></product>`

and it worked